# SchemaBuilder with complex types

Tags: orchardcms

I want to store complex content part record but couldn't create columns with SchemaBuilder in Migrations file.

Here are my classes:

```
public enum BoxInheritance
{
    Empty, Inherit, Enter
}

public class BoxSize
{
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
}

public class BoxSpace
{
    public string Left { get; set; }
    public string Right { get; set; }
    public string Top { get; set; }
    public string Bottom { get; set; }
}

public class BoxPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual BoxSize Size { get; set; }
    public virtual BoxSpace Space { get; set; }
    public virtual Dictionary<string, BoxInheritance> Inheritances { get; set; }

    public BoxPartRecord()
    {
        Size = new BoxSize();
        Space = new BoxSpace();
        Inheritances = new Dictionary<string, BoxInheritance>();
    }
}
```

Is it ok to use a content part record like this?
How to create a table for this content part record?

Answer (score 4):

I think this won't work. My suggestion is to use simple types in the record class and complex types in the content part itself (you can do the mapping there).

```
public class BoxPartRecord
{
  public virtual int Width { get; set; }
  public virtual int Height { get; set; }
  ...
}

public class BoxPart : ContentPart
{
  public BoxSize Size { get { return new BoxSize {record.Width, record.Height} ...
}
```